# Dotnet 5 scaffold changing table names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-5

I have a database with tables like this:
productos
parametros

before .net5 when I run the Scaffold command

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "..............." "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" -o dbFacturacion -f
```

I got the classes like this:

```
Productos
Parametros
```

But after I upgrade to .net5 after run the Scaffold command now the classes are like this:

```
Producto
Parametro
```

What I can do to keep the old table name format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because pluralization is enabled by default in EF Core 5.

Use the --no-pluralize option

Comment: Using .NET 6 I'm getting: Scaffold-DbContext : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'no-pluralize'.

Comment: In powershell it should be `-NoPluralize` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext, which is different from the cli https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold

Answer (score 2):

In PMC the option is -NoPluralize